# Telethon, can I log in to many clients? What are the telegram limits?

Tags: telegram, telethon

How are you?

I am developing a telegram service for my clients.

I wanted to know if using the telegram API I can develop a service that manages the Telegram account of each client of mine (and if I can do this at scale with my api_id and hash_id) or does Telegram put some kind of restrictions?

Being able to develop this would be of great value to my clients but first I want to know if I am breaking any telegram rules. I was looking but I did not find anything very clear.

The main functionalities would be to manage your chats, folders, push notifications.

Do you know with what precautions I must have to develop this?

Thanks!!

Comment: As long as you comply with https://telegram.org/tos and https://core.telegram.org/api/terms, you're probably fine. Official clients, like Telegram for Android, have millions of users under the same API ID and hash.

Comment: Thanks @Lonami

I see that the bot API has limits on sending messages, but they dosn't say anything about the client api. With the api the limits are too much open".

For example if we have hundred of clients and each client send hundred of messages at 'same time' (and the recipients accept and want to receive these messages (they are not really spam). Is this spam for telegram? Or what they consider "spam"?

Comment: Limits are unknown and vary under many conditions. There is no fixed definition. They  could change at any time, for any reason.